# Overheating problems with Java

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.10, ubuntu-mate

I'm using 19.10 Mate, 5.3.0-55-generic  over a samsung rc530/730:

my cpu:

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GH
```

my memory:

```
natty@natty-RC530-RC730:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5855        3565         156         649        2132        1352
Swap:          2047         211        1836
```

my video card:

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

My video driver now are nVidia 340, after switching from 390 for check if I've some benefit using binary drivers, but nothing change. The suggest one from nVidia is the 390 by the way. But as I said nothing change switching it.

I've seen that mainly, java programs make make my system freeze and reboot for thermal problem.

```
natty@natty-RC530-RC730:~$ java --version
java 14.0.1 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I update it from an old relase, but the problem is still there.

Fans are clean, not dust on it.
what do you suggest me for not buy a new laptop and using docker and an IDE like phpstorm, without cry a lot?

---

```
natty@natty-RC530-RC730:~$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l 
java-14-oracle 1091 /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle
```

Comment: What does `prime-select query` show? How do you know it related to overheating?

Comment: @Pilot6 its about overheating because when it freeze this message is showed to me before all turn off. prime-select status not works, i can say that from nVidia settings ive selected performance mode.

Comment: So switch prime-select to Intel and see if this helps.

Comment: @Pilot6 are months that im trying wich is the most convenient...but nothing change

Comment: There are utilities around to show fan speeds... That would be a clue. I had a similar problem a long time ago, solved it by running CPU-intensive processes running on battery only, the system self-limited itself when on battery and so produced a lot less heat.

Comment: @user68186 It is not about hardware recommendations. Read the title TWICE. ;-)

Comment: @JahStation It loooks like you are using Oracle Java. Please add output of `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question. Regarding the hardware - is is absolutely capable to perform well. Two things which are recommended - put here 8 or 16 Gb of RAM and SSD. Upgrading to 20.04.1 LTS in July is good too. Check RAM usage while running Java applications. As for me - the RAM is the limit here. Which temperatures do you have normally and on high load?

Comment: @user68186 I changed the title. I was confused too.

Comment: why updated the title post without asking? its just a supposition that is java the problem untill now...

Comment: @N0rbert 'natty@natty-RC530-RC730:~$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-14-oracle                 1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle' but keep in mind that i switch to the oracle version for trying to resolve this problem...nothing change.

Comment: "switch prime-select to Intel and see if this helps" is still unanswered and yet you decided to post another question for the same problem. Yes, any expert or just knowledgeable person would suspect of an issue with the discrete GPU (Nvidia) whereas the integrated (embedded on the CPU) Intel GPU is probably working fine as suggested by what happens in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Double, or even triple check if your fans are OK.

Check if your thermal paste is in good condition, I highly recommend using a good one instead of the default one.

See the temperatures at the boot-up, maybe it's a clock problem where ur CPU is always clocked at its highest level.

Clean up your PC, not just the fans.

Comment: ive clean all before asking! i will check cpu temp at the start and i will compare it after the system loading... to me is about java btw